# streams illegal exception while collecting

Tags: java-8, java-stream, illegalstateexception

i am trying to perform nested loop of streams. while i collect the result in list it Throws "illegal state exception" stating that steam is closed

```
public void execute(Stream<Trade> trade, Stream<Order> order){

  order.filter(o -> trade.anyMatch(t -> t.getInstrumentId() == 
   o.getInstrumentId() && t.getGroupid() == o.getGroupId()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());// Illegal exception only when i include this line

}
```

Exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

i know that we should not use stream more than once, but in this case i am just filtering and then collecting.. till filtering it doesnot show up an error but while collecting it throws this exception.

Comment: The callback predicate passed to filter() is called for every element of the order stream. So you're calling trade.anyMatch() for every element of order. That is more than once. And you know you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

- The `order` stream is used once
- The `trade` steam is not

You write that for each element of the `order` stream, you'll need to check a condition based on the content of `trade` but you can iterate it only once, here is the problem.

You may pass the `Collection` from which comes the `trade` stream instead.